# Perl: how to designate rows starting with "/"

Tags: perl

I have a file called `list.txt` which looks like so: (it has over 500 rows)

```
/apps/gtool/0.7.5/gtool -M --g gen1.txt etc
/apps/gtool/0.7.5/gtool -M --g gen2.txt etc
/apps/gtool/0.7.5/gtool -M --g gen3.txt etc
```

I want to make .sh script with each line of list.txt. I can do this in Perl but I have an issue as I don't know how to *designate* a line starting with `/`

My script is as follows:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open (IN, "<list_for_merging_chunks.sh");
while (<IN>)
{
    if ($_=~ m/^/apps.*\n/)
    {
    my $file = $_;
    $file =~ s/.*\> //;
    $file =~ s/\.txt/.sh/;
    $file =~ s/\n//;
    open (OUT, ">$file");
    print OUT "\#!/bin/bash\n\#BSUB -J \"$file\"\n\#BSUB -o 
/scratch/home/\n\#BSUB -e /scratch/home/$file\.out\n#BSUB -n 1\n\#BSUB -q 
normal\n\#BSUB -P DBCDOBZAK\n\#BSUB -W 168:00\n";
    print OUT $_;
    close OUT;
    }

}

exit;
```

I get an error:

```
Bareword found where operator expected at merging_chunks.pl line 7, near "*\n"
    (Missing operator before n?)
"my" variable $file masks earlier declaration in same statement at 
merging_chunks.pl line 10.
"my" variable $file masks earlier declaration in same scope at 
merging_chunks.pl line 11.
"my" variable $file masks earlier declaration in same scope at 
merging_chunks.pl line 12.
"my" variable $file masks earlier declaration in same scope at 
merging_chunks.pl line 14.
"my" variable $file masks earlier declaration in same scope at 
merging_chunks.pl line 15.
"my" variable $file masks earlier declaration in same statement at 
merging_chunks.pl line 15.
"my" variable $file masks earlier declaration in same statement at 
merging_chunks.pl line 15.
"my" variable $_ masks earlier declaration in same scope at merging_chunks.pl 
line 16.
syntax error at merging_chunks.pl line 7, near "*\n"
syntax error at merging_chunks.pl line 20, near "}"
Execution of merging_chunks.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

I think this is to do with this file: `if ($_=~ m/^/apps.*\n/)`
It doesn't seem to like the fact it starts with a `/`. Is there anyway I can get around this? I'm assuming there is a special character I could use to somehow tell Perl? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape meta characters in regular expressions with a blackslash.

```
m/^\/apps.*\n/
```

You can also change the delimiter of your pattern match like this.

```
m{^/apps.*\n}
```

You do seem to know that, as you've already done it in your double quoted string further below in your code.

Note that you do not need the `$_ =~` part if you operate on `$_`. If you use `m//` it's implied to be on `$_`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the regexpr delimiter by a character not used inside the regexpr. In this example, I use the `!` instead of `/`:

```
$_=~ m!^/apps.*\n!
```

or scape the / character:

```
$_ =~ m/^\/apps.*\n/
```